# Fetch 'DocIcon' in REST api call

Tags: 2013, rest

I have to display other site collection list data in root site. I am using REST API call to do that. But I am stuck while fetching 'DocIcon'. Can anyone tell me how can I get it?

Here is my code sample:

```
var folderUrl = '/sites/docs/Health%20safety%20and%20environment/Emergency%20Response';
var url ="http://sharepoint.com/sites/docs/_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + folderUrl + "')?$expand=Folders,Files";

$.getJSON(url,function(data,status,xhr){

for(var i = 0; i < data.Files.length;i++){
        $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(data.Files[i].DocIcon),
        $('<td>').text(data.Files[i].Name),
        $('<td>').text(data.Files[i].TimeLastModified.substring(0, 10))).appendTo('#records_table');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "DocIcon" property will not get you the icon itself but the file extension.

You can use mapToIcon method from the SPWeb object in JavaScript to get the image url.

Example :
http://onlinecoder.blogspot.ca/2014/03/get-oob-document-type-icon-using.html

Comment: I am not able to get office files icons

Comment: Do you get an error ?

Comment: No its blank image. But I found a work around. I checked if '.gif' icon exist or not. If it does not exist I check if '.png' icon exist. If both are missing then I display general file icon else which ever is exist.